# Frequency response $H(e^{-j\omega})$ and calculating its magnitude

Tags: signal-processing

Determine the frequency response $H(e^{j\omega})$ of a system characterized by $h(n) = (0.9)^n u(n)$

using the definition 
$$H(e^{j\omega})=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty h(n) e^{-j\omega n}$$
$H(e^{j\omega})=\sum_0^\infty (0.9)^n e^{-j\omega n}$  = $\sum_0^\infty (0.9 e^{-j\omega})^n$ = $$\frac{1}{1-0.9e^{-j\omega}}$$

I understand the above but my question comes when the book tries to get the magnitude of $H(e^{j\omega})$.

$$|H(e^{j\omega})| = \sqrt \frac{1}{(1-0.9 \cos\omega)^2+(0.9 \sin\omega)^2}$$

I know that the use of Euler's formula and the complex conjugate is involved. However, I need to see the math.

Answer (score 1):

Using that $\,e^{j \alpha}=\cos \alpha + j \sin \alpha\,$and $\,|z| = \sqrt{\operatorname{Re}^2(z)+\operatorname{Im}^2(z)}\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{1-0.9e^{-j\omega}}\right| &= \frac{1}{\;|1-0.9e^{-j\omega}|\;} \\
 &= \frac{1}{\;|1 - 0.9 \big( \cos(-\omega)+j \sin(-\omega)\big)|\;} \\
 &= \frac{1}{\;|\big(1 - 0.9 \cos(\omega)\big) - 0.9\,j \sin(\omega))|\;} \\
 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\big(1 - 0.9 \cos(\omega)\big)^2+\big(0.9 \sin(\omega)\big)^2}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't have figured it out myself. Btw shouldn't that be '- 0.9*j*sin(w)' instead of just  '-j*sin(w)' in the third line of the solution?

Comment: @RSMITH Right, thanks, fixed now.